# Get picture position in Apache POI from docx-document

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi, image

I read docx-document that contains text and some pictures.
I can call:
`List<XWPFPictureData> pictures = xwpfDoument.getAllPictures()`

But it returns list of all pictures in the document without theirs positions. I know about method: `List<XWPFPicture> pictures = run.getEmbeddedPictures();`but it return always empty list.

How I can get position of each image in the document?

Comment: What version of POI are you using? And if it's not the latest, have you tried that too?

Comment: I used _3.7_ and _3.8beta3_. Also build library from SVN (it's _3.8beta4_)

Comment: Problem resolved.

It was my own bug: I remove empty runs before reading images. And because XWPFRuns with pictures haven't textual content they was removed like empty runs

Comment: I'd suggest you put this into an answer, then mark it as accepted so it's clear to everyone that the issue is resolved (that's the normal StackOverflow way)

Comment: Still, how did you manage to get picture position having XWPFPicture ? I've tried and I can get those coordinates. Only thing I found is pictures.get(0).getCTPicture().getSpPr().getXfrm().getExt().getCx() but it seems not to be valid coordinates ?

Comment: @AlexanderS. : post the answer, how to get the position of image.
How to insert an image in particular position.

Comment: I have the same problem as you. And I find `run.getEmbeddedPictures()` return pictures for some docx files, return empty list for some other docx files, even they have images embedded. But `docx.getAllPictures()` works well for all instances. I am using POI v3.9.